# How quickly should a process exit after receiving SIGTERM?

Tags: linux, exit, sigterm

Is there some guideline on how much time a linux process should maximally take to exit after receiving a SIGTERM signal?

EDIT: I'm asking because I have to decide on timeouts for blocking I/O calls.

Comment: I've seen some taking up to 5 seconds, but I'd rather say as fast as possible. Close open connections, save setings & data, clear memory, an that's it. Other times I've seen cases where the SIGTERM has been remaped to another functionality.

Comment: @Falk: that should have been an answer

Comment: I'm asking because I need to decide on timeouts for blocking i/o calls.

Comment: @FranBorcic: that should go in the question, you should edit it

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any reference about, I can't just write this as an answer.

Comment: Timeouts shouldn't matter because your I/O will be interrupted and you will get errno==EINTR.

Comment: In my case, it won't. It's too complex to elaborate here, but it involves multiple python threads blocked not only by system I/O, but also by threading control locks.

Comment: What kind of I/O calls do you have? If they are hdd I/O you can give it time since the hdd usualy don't just disapers. It's diferent if they are network I/O because network conections may break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no maximum.  A process can simply ignore `SIGTERM`.  It can be stopped, in which case it won't handle the `SIGTERM` until it gets a `SIGCONT`.  It can be blocked in an uninterruptible system call. (I don't have a current example, but I certainly remember uninterruptible reads/writes when a hard mounted NFS server had failed. And if you happen to be writing your own kernel modules, well...) Finally, if the system is under heavy load, it can take much longer for the process to respond to the signal.